# Как разбить цифры на запятые

Tags: php

подскажи пожалуйста как можно разбить цифры на запитые.

Пример вывода с таблицы
224424596598654265948532164235689

Как сделать так чтобы было вот так
224424596,598654265,548532164,235689251

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
    echo $row;
}
```

Comment: используйте [регулярные выражения](https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/484048/)

Comment: `echo  $row,",";` Пожалуйста, изучите [документацию](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.echo.php).

Comment: И красный блок [вот тут](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php) изучите

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно чего вы конкретно хотите добиться. Вы хотите вывести список ID'в пользователей через запятую? В таком случае достаточно просто добавить запятую к строке

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['id'].",";
}
```

Если вам нужно получить ряд ID'шников безо всяких разделителей, а затем вставить через каждый n-ый символ запятую (зачем?) - тут либо регулярные выражения, либо какой-то такой костыль:

```
$string = "224424596598654265948532164235689";
$stringWithCommas = "";

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++){
    // Если i без остатка делится на 4, и i не 0 (добавление запятой через каждые 4 символа)
    if($i % 4 == 0 && $i > 0) $stringWithCommas.=",";
    $stringWithCommas.=$string[$i];
}

echo $stringWithCommas;
```

Ну и просто к слову, лучше не используйте для работы с БД устаревшие функции. Можно использовать, например, какой-нибудь PDO..

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', 'root');
foreach($dbh->query("SELECT `id` FROM `users`") as $index => $row) {
    if($index > 0) echo ",";
    echo $row['id'];
}
```

Comment: Лучше `!($i+1)%4` и строчкой ниже =)